# Код python не работает?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не совсем понятно почему код выдает ошибку, код и ошибка прикреплены последовательно

```
import unittest

class TestCalc(unittest.TestCase):
    def add(one, two): 
        return one + two

    def test_add(self):                               
        result = add(10, 5)
        self.assertEqual(result, 15)

if __name__ == '__main__':                         
    unittest.main()
```

Ошибка:

python3 unit_tests.py

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_add (__main__.TestCalc)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "unit_tests.py", line 8, in test_add
    result = add(10, 5)
NameError: name 'add' is not defined

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: self.add не пробовали?

Comment: @danilshik `add` не принимает `self`, так что не сработает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы забыли указать, где искать метод

```
result = TestCalc.add(10, 5)
```

Comment: Почему если вынести функцию add() вне класса то это работает?

Comment: Потому что функции верхнего уровня ищутся в пространстве имён текущего модуля, а у класса собственное пространство имён, ограничивающее видимость методов и атрибутов.

Comment: и еще если можно объясните пожалуйста назначение параметра <self> в функции test_add(self)

Comment: Это ссылка на объект, метод которого вызывается.

Comment: `self` дает доступ к пространству имен объекта класса. По сути `self == TestCalc()`, в общем случае.

Comment: то есть, мы наследуем метод класса unittest.TestCase и через ссылку неявно созданного объекта класса TestCalc вызываем унаследованный метод TestCase?